# To walk away when it comes to the time of day

Tags: php, sql

it is such that I need to find out the sql about that "" should not be there that day., and I also find out eventually if I set it to 21:00 so 1.21 must be gone!

right now it works with date, but right now it seems the time.

**this does not work**

```
SELECT title, Dato, Tidspunkt, antal 
FROM tilmeldt 
WHERE Dato >= CURDATE() Tidspunkt > TIME() 
ORDER BY Dato DESC
```

This works 100%

```
SELECT title, Dato, Tidspunkt, antal 
FROM tilmeldt 
WHERE Dato >= CURDATE() 
ORDER BY Dato DESC
```

The problem is: when it has come to the time of day so it must get away right now, nothing happens.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tilmeldt` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `info` longtext COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `Dato` date NOT NULL,
  `Tidspunkt` time NOT NULL,
  `antal` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `opret_navn` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `opret_email` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `opret_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Data dump for tabellen `tilmeldt`
--

INSERT INTO `tilmeldt` (`id`, `title`, `info`, `Dato`, `Tidspunkt`, `antal`, `opret_navn`, `opret_email`, `opret_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Hello World', '<p>ehhehehe</p>', '2013-08-02', '16:00:00', 0, 'Jesper', 'jp@hey.dk', 1),
(2, 'herherh', '<p>hererh</p>', '2013-08-02', '21:00:00', 1, 'Jesper', 'jp@hey.dk', 1);
```

Comment: I don't undestand your question. What must get away right now - and what do you mean by that? What are yot trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are missing logical operator either `AND` or `OR` in between the conditions in the where clause.  Try the following (I'm assuming `AND` here):

```
SELECT title, Dato, Tidspunkt, antal 
FROM tilmeldt 
WHERE Dato >= CURDATE() AND Tidspunkt > TIME(NOW()) ORDER BY Dato DESC
```

**Update:**

Also you were missing argument to `time()` function.  See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time.

Alternatively you can use `current_time()` function like follows:

```
SELECT title, Dato, Tidspunkt, antal 
FROM tilmeldt 
WHERE Dato >= CURDATE() AND Tidspunkt > CURRENT_TIME() ORDER BY Dato DESC
```

Select code used in fiddle (formatted time in result):

```
SELECT title, Dato, time_format('%H-%i-%s', Tidspunkt) as Tidspunkt, antal 
FROM tilmeldt 
WHERE Dato >= CURDATE() AND Tidspunkt > CURRENT_TIME() ORDER BY Dato DESC
```

Comment: it did not bother to work at all even though I write AND, OR .. it will not show content if content has date tomorrow. :O

Comment: @JesperPetersen, please try `Tidspunkt > TIME(NOW())` instead of `Tidspunkt > TIME()`.  I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: It can not help but I just add some of my sql up at the top so you can see if you can use some information there :) I add it now so you can see it :) @vinodadhikary

Comment: IT WORKS NOW! and thanks for the delicious help! @vinodadhikary :)

Comment: i have like you **Answer!**